# Is there a solution to the error: The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a solution to the error: The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

My Code:

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  UserModel({this.uid});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [null safety feature](https://dart.dev/null-safety).
You can do this:

add default value to your parameter

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  UserModel({this.uid = ''});
}
```

or define parameter nullable

```
class UserModel {
  final String? uid;
  UserModel({this.uid});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use the following command "flutter run --no-sound-null-safety" do I still need to make this change?

Comment: if in `pubspec.yaml` you have this constraint, your code is null-safety. `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`. if you want disable null-safety change to it `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: You can also make the parameter required `  UserModel({required this.uid });`